# SharePoint UserProfileService Web Services Permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, sharepoint, savon

I'm using a Ruby gem called Savon to interact with SharePoint 2010's UserProfileService Web Service. I'm getting an error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. I used

```
client.wsse.credentials "username", "password"
```

to pass my credentials. Anyone know what permissions are needed to use the UserProfileService web service?

Answer (score 1):

In SP 2007, the username/password you use will need to have the "Manage User Profiles" permission set in the Shared Service Provider (SSP). IN SP 2010, I am not sure what the equivalent is since there is no longer an SSP, but an User Profile Service. I am sure there is something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In Manage service applications in Central Admin, click on the User Profile Service then click Permisions in the ribbon add the user with Full Control permissions